# Foreground notification service sometimes gets stopped on its own and after sometime starts automatically in nougat

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground-service

I have a never-ending foreground service which shows a notification, but in my device which is having an Android version as nougat.
For some time the notification is not visible(i think most probably because the service has stopped working) and after some time it is visible again automatically.

So I am not able to detect what exactly can be a reason for this.

Attaching the code part in which I have started the service.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
            //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"100")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#00f6d8"))
                    .setContent(notificationView)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
                    .setOngoing(true).build();

            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification);

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
```

Comment: Did the device go to sleep or doze mode when it stopped ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#bg-opt Please check this

Comment: You should migrate to JobScheduler

Comment: Actually, I don't know if it is happening because of doze or sleep mode. Can it happen if I remove all apps from the background or remove other notifications? Because I noticed one case when I was using uber or ola and removed that app and its notification from background and then I saw that my service notification was also not visible.

Comment: did you mean force stop ? what does mean"remove all apps from background" , maybe you mean clear apps from stack ?

Comment: yes, clearing apps from the recent apps button in the device.

Comment: Please use return START_STICKY; instead of return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

Comment: try it and let me know

Comment: START_STICKY makes the app crash as when the service is restarted, START_STICKY returns intent.getAction() == null.

Comment: do not start the service if service is already running, before starting the service check if the service is running is or not

Comment: also "when the service is restarted" what are you doing to restart the service?